# Determining of two arbitrary module are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Given two arbitrary module $M$ and $N$ is there any standard procedure to check weather they are isomorphic or not?

Comment: Probably depends on how the modules are given to you.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: no.

A little longer answer: in contrast to the case of vector spaces (i.e. modules over a field) there is no general invariant like dimension that one can check in order to see if two modules are isomorphc.

Nevertheless there some techinques which can be used to solve the problem for some subclasses of modules: for instance you can still use the dimension if you are working with free modules, you can compare presentations if you are working with finitely presented modules...

Anyway that was to be expected, proving that things are isomorphic is a very hard problem in mathematics, usually it's easier to prove that two things aren't isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is hard even when the ring of scalars has nice properties.

The theory of canonical forms for linear transformations is a theory of isomorphisms of $K[X]$-modules. This theory is very nontrivial and depends on the properties of the field $K$ and how polynomials over $K$ factor into irreducible, especially linear, factors.

The classification of finitely generated abelian groups is a theory of $\mathbb Z$-modules. Like the example above, it is a particular case of the classification of finitely generated over PIDs. The main computational procedure is the [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form).